# 3 different applications and docker containers

Tags: python, docker, containers

I want to setup Kabana and Elastic Search **in Docker** locally first to display logs from a Python web app which isn't in a docker container locally. Although, on a server the Python app is in a docker container.

Kabana and Elastic Search aren't setup on a server and locally yet at all.

- Is it possible to put Kabana and Elastic Searcn into different docker containers or should they be put into a single one? UPDATE: Which option is recommended?
- If the single one, there's no docker image available where both  Kabana and Elastic Search exist, what can I do about that?
- Will they be able to retrieve logs from my Python web app locally which isn't in a docker container or will I have to put the python app into a container as well? If the later, can it be separate container or should I put it into the same one as Kibana and Elastic Search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will try to answer your questions:

1. Yes, It's possible, because the container can comunnicate with another container.

> Links allow containers to discover each other and securely transfer information about one container to another container. When you set up a link, you create a conduit between a source container and a recipient container. The recipient can then access select data about the source. To create a link, you use the --link flag.

2. You can create a custom image.

> Docker can build images automatically by reading the instructions from a Dockerfile. A Dockerfile is a text document that contains all the commands a user could call on the command line to assemble an image. Using docker build users can create an automated build that executes several command-line instructions in succession. More -> https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/

3. You better put in a container and can be separated without any problem.

To better manage all your settings, I suggest you take a look at [Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/).

Here's an example of how the settings would be two containers being linked:

```
elasticsearch:
  image: elasticsearch
  ports:
    - 9200:9200

kibana:
  image: kibana
  ports:
    - 5601:5601
  environment:
    - ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://elasticsearch:9200
  links:
    - elasticsearch
```

Comment: 1) which option is recommended?

Comment: I really prefer to use separate containers. Because this way, I can better manage applications.

Comment: Can I do just `docker run elasticsearch` and `docker run kibana` and then from there manually feed the logs to elasticsearch and see the result in kibana?

Comment: Yes! You can do that. But, you need to understand how the communicate works. See this doc -> https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/container-communication/

Answer (score 1):

The short answer: Yes, you're own Dockfile, and Yes.

Docker containers can communicate over shared volumes and network bridges.
https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/containers/dockervolumes/
https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/containers/networkingcontainers/

As far as your local python application, it depends on the implementation. If you're writing to a local file, then a volume is the best approach. The volume is a local host directory that you map to a path inside a container.

If you're doing it over a network protocol, then you want to expose the port of the container so that your python application can access it.

Now regarding your question about potentially making your own image. This is fairly easy to do. I would start by creating a file called 'Dockerfile` with a base image like Ubuntu

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
```

Then I would add install commands to install your required packages

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install openjdk-7-jre
RUN apt-get install ... (etc)
```

Essentially, you want to create the steps of configuring a new install in your `Dockerfile`
https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/containers/dockerimages/

Comment: is it better to put kibana and elastic in a separate containers or the same one?

Comment: @Dett yes, it would be easier to separate them. It leads to easier management if and when you need to scale.